# Why is there no output showing in this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
man=[]

other=[]

try:
    data=open('sketch.txt')
    for each_line in data:
        try:
            (role,line_spoken) = each_line.split(':',1)
            line_spoken= line_spoken.strip()
            if role == 'Man':
                man.append(line_spoken)
            elif role == 'Other Man':
                other.append(line_spoken)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    data.close()

except IOError:
    print('The datafile is missing!')
try:
    man_file=open('man_data.txt','w')
    other_file=open('other_data.txt','w')
    print(man, file=man_file)
    print(other, file=other_file)
    man_file.close()
    other_file.close()
except IOError:
    print('File error.')
```

Shouldn't it create man_data and other_data file?
There is no error message or any kind of input in the idle.

[image]

Comment: You haven't specified a path, so it created those files in whatever the working directory is.

Comment: i did specify the path beforehand.

Comment: I tried putting 'r' ,it did not work.

Comment: @Efferalgan `'r'` is the default argument of not specified.

Comment: As Arthur Tacca mentioned in his answer, the code you posted is absolutely right. However, the code in the screenshot is wrong. They differ slightly in their indentation and that is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indentation in your screenshot is different from your question. In your question you claimed your code was this (with some bits trimmed out):

```
try:
    # Do something
except IOError:
    # Handle error
try:
    # Write to man_data.txt and other_data.txt
except IOError:
    # Handle error
```

But your screenshot shows that you actually ran this code:

```
try:
    # Do something
except IOError:
    # Handle error
    try:
        # Write to man_data.txt and other_data.txt
    except IOError:
        # Handle error
```

The whole of the second `try`/`except` block is within the `except` clause of the first one, so it will only be executed if there is an exception in the first `try` block. The solution is to run the code that is in your question i.e. unindent the second `try`/`except` block so that it is at the same level as the first one.

Comment: @SiHa I think it gives the original poster more than enough information to answer it themselves, and includes an explanation of the problem rather than just a recipe to fix it. To spell it out though: use the code you said you used, not the code you actually did use. To be even more explicit: Unindent the second `try`/`except` block to be at the same level as the first `try`/`except` block.

Comment: @SiHa Perhaps you just missed the main part of the answer, since it is a bit buried. I've made it bold now to make it a bit easier to pick out.

Comment: Ah. I'll be honest, it's not terribly clear now, but I see where you are coming from. Apologies.

Comment: Your answer is right, but you should try to be more explicit. it took me a bit to understand that the code he posted is RIGHT, but the code in his screenshot is not.

Comment: @Rodolfo and SiHa Thanks for the feedback everyone. I rewrote it to try and be a bit clearer.

Comment: @JodhSingh Glad to hear it. Please click on the tick next to the answer to mark it as accepted